# Remove NO_ZERO_DATE flag from mysql workbench to enable SuiteCRM to work correctly

Tags: bash, mysql-workbench, suitecrm

I need to remove NO_ZERO_DATE flag from mysql workbench. It is stopping SuiteCRM from operating correctly. Removes my ability to create campaigns for example and throws up numerous errors.

Unfortunately I a root user and using my SSH client I can type in commands but it is BASH which uses slightly different commands what I find online. I am not sure exactly what to type in order to remove the NO_ZERO_DATE flag and I am not sure if I should entirely remove Strict Mode, which it appears to be.

I am using
*GNU bash, version 4.2.46(2)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)" adn the commands are slightly different*
I work in *SQL in MYSQLworkbench 6.3 CE*

I know this is likely a very simple question for someone with the correct knowledge, I just need to know exactly what to type to remove the flag.

```
New action with error
Ran [root@server ~]# mysqld --sql mode="NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"

got 
[root@server ~]# mysqld --sql mode="NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"
2018-09-19T13:58:48.915959Z 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
2018-09-19T13:58:48.917012Z 0 [Note] mysqld (mysqld 5.7.23) starting as process 23382 ...
2018-09-19T13:58:48.918011Z 0 [ERROR] Fatal error: Please read "Security" section of the manual to find out how to run mysqld as root!

2018-09-19T13:58:48.918039Z 0 [ERROR] Aborting

2018-09-19T13:58:48.918071Z 0 [Note] Binlog end
2018-09-19T13:58:48.918114Z 0 [Note] mysqld: Shutdown complete
```

Tried root@server ~]# mysqld --sql mode="NO_ZERO_DATE"

```
[    root@server ~]# mysqld --sql mode="NO_ZERO_DATE"
    2018-09-19T14:00:18.665452Z 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
    2018-09-19T14:00:18.666463Z 0 [Note] mysqld (mysqld 5.7.23) starting as process 23484 ...
    2018-09-19T14:00:18.667446Z 0 [ERROR] Fatal error: Please read "Security" section of the manual to find out how to run mysqld as root!

    2018-09-19T14:00:18.667490Z 0 [ERROR] Aborting

    2018-09-19T14:00:18.667508Z 0 [Note] Binlog end
    2018-09-19T14:00:18.667551Z 0 [Note] mysqld: Shutdown complete
```

Answer (score 0):

You should change the default `sql_mode` for mysql.

Usually the default has the NO_ZER_DATE set, you can just take that option ouy so uou can set it to:

`ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION`

You can either do that on the mysql config file (this is what you want to make suitecrm run ok) or for the session doing something like `SET sql_mode = 'NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION'  ;`  (this command is a mysql query)

Look for your mysql config file, in ubuntu is located in 
 `/etc/mysql/conf.d/mysql.cnf`
Add the sql-mode line with something like this:

```
[mysqld]
sql-mode="NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"
```

Comment: Hi When I type  [root@server ~]# SET sql_mode = 'NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION';
States - bash: SET: command not found. The mysql config file does not appear to have the NO_ZERO_DATE in it either. Do you know what the correct command is in bash?

Comment: that wasn't a bash command, it was a mysql command. Nevertheless I updated the answer including the location of the mysql config file and a working example